# Angular js multiple or single controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular.js and i have made an html page which will bind the json data. I am quite confused with the angular.js controllers. Like should I make one controller which will be generic or to make separate controllers for each html page? any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what the pages do and how similar they are.  Typically, each controller has its own page, but if the pages are extremely similar in nature, a slightly more abstract controller may make sense to avoid code duplication.

Another approach, depending on what your app is doing, is to move all the common logic into a service, which multiple controllers call into.

Whatever the case, you should use tactics to avoid code duplication and maintain the Single Responsibility Principal wherever possible.